# Manual deployment after pre-approval in Azure DEVOPS

Tags: azure-devops

I am working on setting up pre-deployment approval for my releases on Azure DEVOPS. 
The issue that I am facing at the moment is that once the authorised person approve the request the release is automatically deployed to the environment. I want the release to be not deployed until the guy requesting it click the deploy button after the pre-deployment approval. The setting I have at the moment:
[image]
[image]

As soon as the user approves the deployment it is automatically deployment. I want the deployment to be manual triggered after approval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As soon as the user approves the deployment it is automatically deployment. I want the deployment to be manual triggered after approval.

I am afraid we could not deployment to be manual triggered after approval (At least not currently).

I used to have the same requirement as you, but after communicating with my manager, we found that such request would pose a risk. For example, I manually triggered a deployment and got approval from my manager(The Approvers), but if the manual release is still triggered by me, **it will be possible to trigger this deployment during a time period that my manager does not want to deployment**. Obviously this is unreasonable.

Besides, since we select the options `Manual only` and add `Approvers`, that means we are ready for this deployment, and the approvers decides whether to deploy and deploy time.

There is option for approvers to `Defer deployment for later`:

[image]

BTW, if this risk is not what you care about, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Our problem is that approval manager is only working during business hours and they would like to approve the release around that time and want the deployment to be done after hours by support team. I will actually explore the defer option as well.

Comment: @ArunKumar, Got it, we are in the same situation, the option for approvers to Defer deployment for later is our current choice, you can try it, have a nice day!